# Declaring vs Defining member variables C++

Tags: c++

I have seen many questions regarding definition and declaration of global and local variables and static members, but for non-static member variables, I am unable to distinguish it.

In the code below

```
class Line 
{
int length; //?
static int L;  //declared
}; //defined
```

We have defined the class `Line`, we have declared its static member `L`. So what about the non-static member `length`? Is it defined or declared?

Comment: _"Is it defined or declared?"_ Both.

Answer (score 1):

For normal (automatic, non-static) variables, like `length` in your code, declaration without the `extern` keyword is also definition. So `length` is both declared and defined.